# JBoss updates log file after shutdown

Tags: log4j, jboss7.x

We are using Log4J as the application logger. The application EAR is deployed on JBoss 7.1.1. The log4j configuration is as below

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=d:\\loging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

I cannot see the log messages at runtime. However when I shutdown the JBoss server, all the log messages can be seen in the log file.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you excluding the servers log4j dependency and providing your own? https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F

Comment: Yes, I have excluded servers log4j dependency.

Comment: Have you tried setting immediateFlush to true?